# X-Editable in Bootstrap 4 modal not clickable

Tags: bootstrap-4, x-editable

I have a modal in a Bootstrap 4 design that has two XEditable text field on it.

If I set the XEditable option to inline, it works fine (thought the table gets pushed aside, but I guess that's just a CSS fix). However, if it is set to popup, which I want, I can't click the textbox in the pop over?  Anyone have any idea why? I was thinking maybe the order, but not sure on how to change that?

Screenshot attached.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue by removing `tabindex` property from modal `div`.

Here `tabindex` property of modal div conflicts with `select2` property of xeditable.

So simply remove

`tabindex=-1`

or set

```
tabindex=10 or any other value.
```

Answer borrowed from.
[When we use X-editable's "select2" into bootstrap-modal ,it can not focus on search input and not input key word #206](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/206)

Edit: if using Jquery:

```
$(document).off('focusin.modal');
```

On modal shown event

Answer (score 1):

The popup option is not compatible with Bootstrap 4, only inline is working at the moment. The plugin was written for Bootstrap 3 and there are differences in markup that cause this issue.

There is a development branch available for Bootstrap 4, you can try to download it to see if it fixes your issue:

https://github.com/Talv/x-editable/tree/develop/dist/bootstrap4-editable

Comment: FYI the linked version does not fix the problem.